# Custom Button Action in Rails View - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails newbie here. I have an array of hashes that contain Facebook Friends that I'd like to optionally turn into 'Contacts'. I have an index view that lists all of the users's 'friends'. I'd like to have a custom button that enables the user to turn each friend into a contact. How do I do this in Rails?

Index view - I am currently listing each user with their avatar & name. I'd like to add the button in each list item.

Note: I do not have a Friend model, as I am simply pulling this data in from the Facebook Graph API as an array of hashes.

```
<% @friends.each do |friend|%>
<li> <%= image_tag(fb_avatar(friend["id"], "type=square"))%> <%=friend["name"]%> #put button here </li>
<% end %>
```

Custom make_friend_contact method in Application Helper (to be called on a friend):

```
def make_friend_contact
  Contact.new(name: self["name"], uid: self["id"], avatar_url: fb_avatar(self["id"], "type=square"), user_id: params[:user])
end
```

Any help is much appreciated. I've done quite a bit of reading, and I can't seem to crack this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to use button_to. You can check it out in the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/). Here is one of their examples:

```
<%= button_to [:make_happy, @user] do %>
  Make happy <strong><%= @user.name %></strong>
<% end %>

# => "<form method="post" action="/users/1/make_happy" class="button_to">
#      <div>
#        <button type="submit">
#          Make happy <strong><%= @user.name %></strong>
#        </button>
#      </div>
#    </form>"
```

where the button calls the make_happy action in the Users controller on @user.

You could do something similar by making an action in your Users controller that creates a new Contact, using a friend parameter.

```
def make_friend_contact
  friend = params[:friend]
  Contact.new(name: friend["name"]...
end
```

Then you just have to send the friend parameter with the button's POST request.